# .hide() is hiding too much

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to hide the div "loginArea" and then fade in the div "newAccArea". Whenever I try to activate it, it shows the div "newAccArea" for only a moment and then hides it too. I know it sounds like an obvious solution, that I have an extra div or forgot a closing div tag, but I couldn't find any. Please help me out, thank you. Summarized Code HTML:

```
<div class="backarea">
    <div class="loginArea">
        <!--Random Stuff-->
    </div>
    <div class="newAccArea">
        <!--More Random Stuff-->
    </div>
</div>
JQuery:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.createone').click(function(){ //".createone" is nothing you have to //worry about
        $('.loginArea').hide('slow');
        $('.newAccArea').fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});


                         **FULL CODE JUST INCASE**
HTML:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Log in box</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ramabhadra' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Khand:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="successLog">
<div class="header">
    <ul class="cats">
        <li class="listItems" id="home">Home</li>
        <li class="listItems" id="dashboard">Dashboard</li>
        <li class="listItems" id="contactUs">Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class='dropdownHome'>
    <ul class="catLists">
        <li class="catListItem">Event Calender</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Bookings</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Picture Gallery</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Login</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Sign Up</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdownDashboard">
    <ul class="catLists">
        <li class="catListItem">Saved Info</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Friends</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Document</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Profile</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Account</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="dropdownContactUs">
    <ul class="catLists">
        <li class="catListItem">Email</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Forum</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Phone-numbers</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Facebook</li><br>
        <li class="catListItem">Twitter</li>
    </ul>
  </div><Br><Br><Br>
    <h1 class="welcomeBack">Hello! Welcome back to Code Acedamy</h1>
    <!--<button class="logOut">Log Out</button>-->
</div>
<div class="backarea">
    <div class="loginArea">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" class="userInput" name="userInput"><h2 class="username">Username:</h2></input>
        <input type="password" class="passInput" placeholder="Password" name="passInput"<h2 class="password">Password:</h2></input>
        <button class="login">Log In</button>
        <p class="createacc">Don't have an account? <span class="createone">Create one.</span></p>
        <p class="error">Sorry but that username or password is incorrect.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="newAccArea">
        <h1 class="newAccText">Create New Account</h1>
        <h2 class="newUsername" id="position">Username:</h2>
        <input class="newUser" type="text" name="newUser" placeholder="Username" id="position"></input>
        <h2 class="newPassword" id="position">Password:</h2>
        <input class="newPass" type="password" name="newPass" placeholder="Password" id="position"></input>
        <h2 class="newPassword" id="position">Password:</h2>
        <h2 class="confNewPassword" id="position">Confirm Password:</h2>
        <input class="confNewPass" type="password" name="confNewPass" placeholder="Confirm Password" id="position"></input>
        <button class="createAccButt">Create Account</button>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
CSS:

body {
    background-color:#F0F0F0;
}
.successLog {
    background-color:#8A8A8A;
    height:450px;
    width:700px;
    z-index:1;
    opacity:0;
}
/*CREATE NEW ACCOUNT AREA*/
.newAccArea {
    position:relative;
    bottom:500px;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:-5;
}
.newUsername {
    position:relative;
    top:80px;
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.newUser {
    position:relative;
    top:60px;
    left:45px;
    padding:5px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.newPassword {
    position:relative;
    top:42px;
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.newPass {
    position:relative;
    top:23px;
    left:45px;
    padding:5px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.confNewPassword {
    position:relative;
    bottom:50px;
    text-align:center;
    color:black;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.confNewPass {
    position:relative;
    bottom:70px;
    left:45px;
    padding:5px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
.createAccButt {
    color:white;
    background-color:#E60716;
    padding:5px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    border:none;
    margin:10px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:77;
    left:78;
    height:40;
    width:80;
    font-size:20px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.createAccButt:hover {
    background-color:#A81919;
}
.newAccText {
    position:relative;
    top:100px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size:30px;
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
}
/*LOG IN AREA*/
.backarea {
    background-color:#6DE3E3;
    width:255px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:9px;
    position:relative;
    top:67px;
    left:230px;
    position:fixed;
}
.loginArea {
    background-color:#6DE3E3;
    width:255px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:9px;
}
.userInput {
    padding:5px;
    margin:7px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    left:35px;
    border:1px solid white;
}
.userInput:hover {
    border:2px solid #60BF68;
}
.username {
    color:#E60716;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    bottom:50px;
    left:75px;
}
.passInput {
    padding:5px;
    margin:7px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    top:20px;
    left:35px;
    border:1px solid white;
}
.passInput:hover {
    border:2px solid #60BF68;
}
.password {
    color:#E60716;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    position:relative;
    bottom:80px;
    left:75px;
}
.login {
    color:white;
    background-color:#E60716;
    padding:5px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    border:none;
    margin:10px;
    position:relative;
    bottom:60;
    left:71;
    height:40;
    width:80;
    font-size:20px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.login:hover {
    background-color:#B81414;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.createacc {
    position:relative;
    bottom:73px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    padding:8
}
.createone {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#4548E6;
    font-size:13px;
}
.createone:hover {
    color:purple;
}
.error {
    color:red;
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
    font-size:10;
    position:relative;
    bottom:93px;
    text-align:center;
    opacity:0
}
/*DROP DOWN MENU
/*DEFUALT CLASSES*/
.clicked {
    color:#fff;
}
.invis {
    opacity:0;
}
/*HTML CLASSES*/
.header {
    background-color:black;
    height:50px;
    border-radius:10px;
    z-index:10;
}
li {
    color:white;
    display:inline;
    width:100%
}
.cats {
    padding:6px;
    width:100%;
    font-size:27px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
}
.cats .listItems:hover {
    width:100px;
    font-size:27px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    color:#96F29C;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:70px;
}
.cats .listItems:active {
    width:100px;
    font-size:27px;
    font-family: 'Khand', sans-serif;
    color:#318A29;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:70px;
}
.listItems {
    padding:70px;
}
.dropdownHome {
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    position:absolute;
    left:14px;
    bottom:210px;
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:13px;
    opacity:0;
}
.dropdownDashboard {
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    position:absolute;
    left:255px;
    bottom:210px;
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:13px;
    opacity:0;
}
.dropdownContactUs {
    height:200px;
    width:180px;
    background-color:#9E9E9E;
    position:absolute;
    left:507px;
    bottom:210px;
    border:2px solid black;
    z-index:1;
    border-radius:13px;
    opacity:0;
}
.catLists {
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    right:20;
    font-family: 'Ramabhadra', sans-serif;
}
.catListItem {
    color:black;
}
.welcomeBack {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color:blue;
    text-align:center;
}
.logOut {
    position:relative;
    top:130px;
    left:312px;
    padding:5px;
    border:none;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.logOut:hover {
    background-color:#B51919;
    border-top:1px solid #F7A3A3;
    border-left:1px solid #F7A3A3;
}
JavaScript:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.createone').click(function(){
        $('.loginArea').hide('slow');
        $('.newAccArea').fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.login').click(function(){
        var userResult = $('input[name=userInput]').val();
        var passResult = $('input[name=passInput]').val();
        if(userResult === "CodeAcademy" && passResult === "fun-coding" || userResult === "User_Example" && passResult === "Pass_Example") {
           $('.backarea').fadeOut('fast');
           $('.successLog').fadeTo('fast',1);
        }
        else {
        $('.passInput').css('border-color','red');
        $('.userInput').css('border-color','red');
        $('.error').fadeTo('fast',1);
        $('.error').effect( "bounce",{ times: 3 },"slow" );
        };
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').click(function(){
        $('.dropdownHome').slideToggle('slow');
        $('.dropdownHome').fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dashboard').click(function(){
        $('.dropdownDashboard').slideToggle('slow');
        $('.dropdownDashboard').fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contactUs').click(function(){
        $('.dropdownContactUs').slideToggle('slow');
        $('.dropdownContactUs').fadeTo('fast',1);
    });
});
```

Comment: have you checked your browser console for any errors? The jQuery onclick function works just fine on it's own so the issue must be elsewhere. http://jsfiddle.net/ee1jfLjf/

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't see the newAccArea is because you have it relatively positioned 500 pixels from the bottom, which ends up putting all of the content off screen, above the top of the viewport. The reason you're able to see it while the loginArea is fading out is because as long as the loginArea is still visible, the starting point of the newAccArea is lower (300 pixels lower, since the height of loginArea is 300px), so the 500 pixels from the bottom of that starting point is low enough to still see it.

You just need to set the position to what it needs to be, when loginArea isn't displayed, and you should see it fine.

Answer (score 0):

You said `I want to hide the div "loginArea" and then fade in the div "newAccArea".` In this case, you may use a `callback` function to show the `newAccArea` div after the hiding has finished:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.createone').click(function() {
        $('.loginArea').hide('slow', function() {
            // It'll fade in after hiding the .loginArea
            $('.newAccArea').fadeTo('fast', 1);
        });
    });
});
```

Regarding the problem you mentioned, it should not happen according to your code. The `newAccArea` div should not be hidden because it's out side of the `loginArea` div.